# WPF - Mouse wheel scroll not working on a ListBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, mousewheel

I am currently working on a WPF project in C# using MVVM. In this project I have a list box that loads a user control for each row of data in my items source.
My question is, how to I make my listbox have smooth mouse wheel scrolling.
I have below ListBox -

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Celllistbox" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                 SelectionMode="Single" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DetentionLocationsTemplate}"
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 Opacity="1" 
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                 Width="Auto"
                                 MinHeight="100" d:IsLocked="True"
                                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
    
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    
                            <ListBox.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                                    <Border Padding="1,0,1,0" x:Name="celltemplate">
                                        <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0">
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ListBox.Template>
                        </ListBox>
```

Below code is from resource file -

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="DetentionLocationsTemplate">
        <DockPanel Background="{StaticResource ContextMenuBackGroundSolid}" LastChildFill="True">

            <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                  Height="Auto"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="0,0,0,1">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="118"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand" 
                              BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#FF031A44" Margin="1,1,0,0"
                              Background="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_colour, Converter={StaticResource HexValueColourToColor}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource LightBackgroundColorBrush}}">
    
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                                <cinch:EventToCommandTrigger Command="{Binding MouseClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding LocationDetails}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,2,0,0" Text="{Binding stl_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource LabelTextColour}" FontSize="12"/>
    
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="1,0,1,0" Source="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_icon, Converter={StaticResource UrlToImage}, ConverterParameter='true'}" Stretch="Fill" Width="22" Height="22" />
    
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,0,1,0" Text="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_capacity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource ThemisLabelTextColour}" FontSize="12"/>
    
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Margin="1,0,1,0" Fill="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_gendercolour, Converter={StaticResource HexValueColourToColor}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ThemisTileBackgroundColour}}"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_hasgendericon, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}" />
    
                                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Margin="1,0,1,0" Cursor="Arrow" Source="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_gendericon, Converter={StaticResource UrlToImage}, ConverterParameter='true'}" Stretch="Fill" Width="22" Height="22" 
                                                Visibility="{Binding Path=LocationDetails.stl_hasgendericon, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
    
                    <ListBox x:Name="wbrowlistbox" Grid.Column="1" 
                               Margin="0" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Det_Elements}"  
                               Background="Transparent" 
                               Opacity="1" 
                               BorderThickness="0"                                      
                               Height="50"
                               Width="Auto">                    
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource WhiteboardRowTemplate}}" Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <pwcc:TimeLinePanel MinDate="{Binding StartDateTime, Converter={StaticResource UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter}}"
                                                    MaxDate="{Binding EndDateTime, Converter={StaticResource UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter}}"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="pwcc:TimeLinePanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding StartDateTime, Converter={StaticResource UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="pwcc:TimeLinePanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding EndDateTime, Converter={StaticResource UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">                                        
                                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".35"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".55" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".75"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                                                <ContentPresenter 
                                                  x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#5FBDCE" Fill="#5FBDCE" Opacity="0.3" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="2" Visibility="Collapsed" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                       
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    
                    </ListBox>
    
                    <!-- cell tasks and warnings information -->
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" Width="118"
                              BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,1,1,0" 
                              Background="{StaticResource LightBackgroundColorBrush}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                            <!-- tasks -->
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Det_Tasks}"
                                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskIconTemplate}">
                                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Margin="2"
                                                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
    
                            <!-- warnings -->
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WarningSignals}"
                                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SmallIconTemplate}">
                                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>    
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>    
                </Grid>    
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Somehow mouse wheel scroll is not working on this listbox.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to set the ListBox's Template and ItemsPanel? ListBox uses a ScrollViewer and a VirtualizingStackPanel by default.

Comment: Not a particular reason but tried this way to achieve requirement. Not aware about alternatives for the same.

Comment: Don't set it without a reason.

Comment: The control pwcc:TimeLinePanel inside ItemPanel is a requirement so I can not remove it but if I remove it still scroll is not working. The list "wbrowlistbox" has something wrong which I am not getting.